# PHP: Convert html-entity-encoded uppercase character to lowercase

Tags: php, hex, html-entities, lowercase

How can I convert the upper-case html entity characters to their lowercase?

```
$str = "&#xC9;"; //É

$res = strtolower( $str );

echo $res;
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/Zf3RTe

Comment: That was just a typo here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$str = "&#xC9;"; //É

$res = mb_strtolower(html_entity_decode($str,ENT_COMPAT|ENT_HTML401,'UTF-8'),'UTF-8' );

echo $res;
```

Comment: `Warning: html_entity_decode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /in/F6TSA on line 4` http://3v4l.org/F6TSA

Comment: Works in PHP 5.4+ now, generates a notice in 5.0-5.3 (`Use of undefined constant ENT_HTML401`): http://3v4l.org/uWbbu

Comment: well, I misplaced encoding argument at first

Comment: @AlixAxel It does work for `É`. Any example of an uppercase that doesn't convert properly?

Comment: @JanDvorak: `É` is Latin-1. Try any Greek letter for instance.

Comment: @JanDvorak: You're still using the Latin alphabet. Try `ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΉ ΓΛΏΣΣΑ`.

Comment: @AlixAxel What you have posted is already lowercase but it converts to uppercase correctly: http://3v4l.org/Rv3cI

Comment: @AlixAxel any other challenge?

Comment: @JanDvorak: The point was converting hexits to lowercase, hence `$str = &#x395;&#x39B;&#x39B;&#x397;&#x39D;&#x399;&#x39A;&#x389;&#x20;&#x393;&#x39B;&#x38F;&#x3A3;&#x3A3;&#x391;`. Either way, I just tested it and it works with `html_entity_decode`, which is a bit weird because I remember testing it against `mb_convert_encoding` and the charset support was not so extensive back then.

Answer (score 8):

Just use the right function for it:

```
$strLower = mb_strtolower($str, 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

The [PHP  Multibyte String extension<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/book.mbstring) has an encoding for HTML entities (See [list of all supported encodings<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/mbstring.supported-encodings)).

Answer (score 1):

Convert the hexit to decimal and add 32, convert back to hexit.

---

Or using `mbstring`:

```
$res = mb_strtolower(mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES'), 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: It's add 32 to get from uppercase to lowercase.

Comment: @JanDvorak: No, it works for Latin-1 too (with the exception of [`yY`] + `¨`).

Comment: @AlixAxel A solution is searched for that works in the entire unicode range.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Humm... Okay. I'll post something else then.

Comment: Nice one, but rather useless with named entites like `&Uuml;`

Comment: I was commenting before edit. Useless when you don't have hex value in entity.

Answer (score 0):

On my server, I don't have the `mbstring` extension installed. For a better, cross-server solution you should use this instead:

```
echo htmlentities(strtoupper(html_entity_decode($str)));
```